# gridview of images is not getting refreshed

Tags: android, gridview, android-layout, invalidation, android-gridview

i have a grid view with images populated from a list. when i remove an image from the list,i want the grid view to get refreshed.can someone tell me how to do this.

i have tried to invalidate() the gridview, notify the image adapter that the data set has changed(adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();). but this is not giving the desired results.

after doing this i am getting a blank in the place where the image that is removed used to be before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use a ListAdapter to populate your view ? Maybe you should recreate a new adapter when your list changes.

Comment: i am using a custom adapter which extends base adapter

Comment: yes, recreating using a new adapter is the only way i found to be a working solution. Although would like to know if there is any other way.

Comment: this is questionable; don't create a new adapter each time! use invalidateViews() as Denis said..

Answer (score 8):

Try to use gridView.invalidateViews() instead of just .invalidate(). It redraws all views (ImageViews in your case) inside gridView.

Comment: i need to redraw one grid from the gridview how to do that tried the getChildAt, no luck

Comment: You mean that you need to redraw one view (not one grid) from your gridview, right?

Comment: I have found that invalidate() redraws child views properly for API level 9 but not for API level 14.  invalidateViews(), on the other hand, works for API level 14 but for API level 9 it causes the child views to not receive onClick() events - a problem that does not occur for API level 14.